# Props Changed cause component re-Render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-devtools

I have component which receive some props,
I've realized the component renders at unwanted times and cases

So I checked each props explicitly with simple UseEffect hook to find if props are really changed and causes the re-Render.

Indeed, some props is 'changing' when clicking on some buttons, the problem is the props not really changing and even if I put mock data inside the props (propsName={10}), the useEffect hook 'thinks' that the prop is changed.

This is the useEffect hook I've used:

```
UseEffect(() => {
  console.log(`prop has changed', propName)
}, [propName])
```

What could be the problem, Why it looks like the props changed even if it's not really changes?

Comment: could you provide a bit more detail? I have a guess why that is happening, but without knowing the structure it is hard to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` will run on first render of the component, and then any time an item in the dependency changes. Check out the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) for more info on conditionally firing an effect.